# Custom Http Response Exception Mapper in Javalin Server

Tags: javalin

How can we implement a custom exception mapper in the Javalin frame work? The main issue I am having with the default one is that it includes a type field in its json responses that identifies it as a javalin exception. I don't wish to expose this information. It looks as follows:

```
{

    "title": "Internal server error.",

    "status": 500,

    "type": "https://javalin.io/documentation#error-responses",

    .....

}
```

The `HttpResponseExceptionMapper` doesn't seem to be an interface or anything that can be overridden. So I am at a loss, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the code which is generating this JSON? I may have misunderstood the question, but I would have expected you can use `app.exception(Exception.class, (e, ctx) -> { ...build your JSON response here... }` or `app.error(500, ctx -> { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving it by enclosing the code in a try-catch block like this:

```
try {
    throw BadRequestResponse("A parameter is missing")
} catch (e: BadRequestResponse) {
    ctx.json("Bad request: ${e.message}.").status(400)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javalin provides out of the box support for Exception Mapping, you can just do:

```java
app.exception(BadRequestResponse.class, (e, ctx) -> {
    ctx.json("Bad request: ${e.message}.").status(400)
});
```